# element.find("circle").position() is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using d3 tree, and on hover of node I am showing tooltip, but in firefox the position of tooltip is not showing properly..
On chrome it is showing fine.I want it to look as it is like on chrome.

I am using below code:

```
var element = $("#" + d.nodeId);

var pos = element.find('circle.nodeCircle').position();
var rad = element.find('circle.nodeCircle').attr('r');//radius of circle
$('.tooltip').css('left', (pos.left - rad) + 'px');
$('.tooltip').css('top', pos.top + 'px');
```

Also check images for firefox and chrome.
[image: Firefox Screenshot]
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: `.offset()` might help.

check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338594/jquery-position-not-working-correctly-in-safari-and-chrome

Comment: `[...]The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent.[...]` so if your tooltip and the`circle.nodeCircle` don't have the same offset parent, then it won't work the way you do it. As `Ryo` suggest you should use `offset` to get and set the position.

Comment: var middle_top = parseInt($("circle.nodeCircle").offset().top);
       var footer_left = parseInt($("circle.nodeCircle").offset().left);
       $('.tooltip').css('left',middle_top);$('.tooltip').css('left',footer_left);   Used this code also..

Comment: Let me guess the way you wrote it does not work? It is the same situation as before. `offset` is the global position. The `left` and `right` is the local position relative to the offset parent. Thats hay I said that you should use `.offset` to _get_ **AND** _set_ the positions.