# jQuery position() not working properly in Safari and Opera

Tags: jquery, html, safari, position, opera

Need help!! I have this on my page and it works perfectly in chrome, firefox and IE.

[image]

But when I check using Safari and Opera, it shows the result as shown below

[image]

It is weird because it works correctly on some devices, but not all.

I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338594/jquery-position-not-working-correctly-in-safari-and-chrome) and I have removed `margin:0 auto`, the result is still same. Do I have second option? Except change to offset.

Click here for the completed code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eelyn/y9np3gtt/8/)

Comment: Are you really using jq 1.6.4?

Comment: Nop, I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js. Is that related?

Comment: Change the jquery version to 1.6.4 instead of using 1.4 .   With 1.4: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y9np3gtt/9/ . With 1.6.4: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y9np3gtt/10/

Comment: Already changed to 1.6.4, but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Even i have faced the same issues. Sometimes the browsers load the cached data. So try reloading it in private mode. It might work at times.

Comment: I have to make sure it works perfectly, because that is used for my client website. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `margin-left=1px` into trapezium css code as shown below

```
#trapezium {
  width:1511px;
  height:1070px;
  z-index:80;
  position:fixed; 
  margin-left: 1px; }
```

But I don't know why `margin-left` can solved my problem. Anyone know this?

Answer (score -1):

position() relates to the position relative to the containing DOM element, as opposed to the position on screen. The difference is probably caused by differences in the way the element hierarchy is rendered in Webkit browsers, rather than by a bug in jQuery.

You will have to check element hierarchies to find out which DOM element is causing your problem, or, if you want to position your tooltip relative to the position of an element within the window boundaries, use offset() instead

Note:- Even though it's not working just update the browser to latest version.

Comment: So you are just copying/pasting other linked answer?!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5338658/1414562

Comment: I just gave you reference this... instead of pasting link

Comment: Try to install jquery plugins to your browser which will available in app store, as of my idea the name of plugin is the "Jquery Enabling Script"...!

Comment: I think install jquery plugins to browser is not a good solution. It is impossible to inform everyone to install the plugins before they browse it.